# vnc application for iPhone. How to go about building one?

Tags: iphone, vnc

Alright.. I am on a mission to learn iPhone development as much as possible. At my current job they have requested me if I can build a vnc viewer in iPhone.. there are many vnc apps but i want to learn how to build an app like that.. what would be the architecture of this app how should i organize my app?

**Edit: Specific question:**

- Is VNC the best (or the only) opensource protocol to do remote desktop connections?
- What security precautions should one consider when building the client?

Any thoughts? comments?

Comment: This is way too broad of a question to get a clean answer here.  We're not going to plan out and write your application for you, but we would be glad to help you with specific aspects of its implementation.

Answer (score 5):

John,

To help you out. Here's an open source VNC client for Mac OSX. By studying this code you should be able to build yourself a version that compiles using Xcode on iPhone (both use Cocoa).

Good Luck.

http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=386447&group_id=64347

Answer (score 2):

VNC is not only the protocol to do remote desktop connections.

There is RDP and it's have open source freerdp at github.
https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP

There's iOS client source code as well, and also for VNC, you can use this;

https://github.com/leonliu/NPDesktop

Answer (score 1):

this may be a little late, but if you want, you can study the code of [VNsee](http://code.google.com/p/vnsea/)

Comment: were you able to run this project and make the vnc work by anychance?

Answer (score 0):

look at existing apps that use the vnc protocol and distill a feature set from those, then get familiar with the [vnc protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).